# Can't successfully check if post with title exist in database

Tags: php, database

In WordPress, I am trying to import posts from a CSV file. I want to check, if post with title already exist. I am trying to do this using a database query, but I am still able to import the same three posts from my example CSV file.

Following PHP code snippet is what I use for checking, if a post with title already exist:

```
   $check_post_exists = function( $title ) use ( $wpdb, $postTypeArray ) {

        $posts = $wpdb->get_col( "SELECT post_title FROM {$wpdb->posts} WHERE post_type = '{$postTypeArray["custom-post-type"]}' AND post_status = 'publish" );

        return in_array( $title, $posts );
    };

    foreach ( $posts() as $post ) {

        if ( $check_post_exists( $post["zoneid"] ) ) {
            continue;
        }

        $post["id"] = wp_insert_post( array(
            "post_title" => $post["zoneid"],
            "post_content" => $post["bemaerkning"],
            "post_type" => $postTypeArray["custom-post-type"],
            "post_status" => "publish"
        ));         
    }
```

What am I doing wrong or what am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have typing mistake. You are using the double quotation mark instead of single quotation mark at the end of the code `post_status = 'publish"`

Please use  `post_status = 'publish'`  instead of `post_status = 'publish"`    and then use double quotation mark at the end of query.

And also make sure that dynamic values are correctly entered in the query by printing the query before execution.

Comment: You are absolutely right. I missed a single quotation mark. That completely solved my problem.

Thanks a lot!!!